# Mongoid relation throwing NoMethodError: undefined method 'push' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

**Edit: This issue is resolved. The issue was caused by a conflict specific to my application**. Another module dynamically created a method named `.sources`. I was able to troubleshoot by removing the relationship and inspecting the objects method list. Thanks anyways.

I'm using Rails 4.1 with Mongoid 4.0 and have setup a relation as follows:

```
class Organization
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :sources
end
```

and

```
class Source
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

Then in my rspec test I have:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe PartnershipsController, :type => :controller do
describe "POST #record" do
  it "should create a partnership for the source's organization" do
    organization = FactoryGirl.create(:organization)
    source = FactoryGirl.create(:source)
    organization.sources.push source
  end
end
```

There's more after, but the test fails at the `organization.sources.push source` line with:

```
undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't understand why the error is happening. Looks like in the [mongoid documentation](http://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many) that's how I should be adding the related source, but so far no dice. What is the correct way to make this relation?

**Edit: adding factory**

Here's the organization factory, in case it helps clarify something:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :organization do
    app_name = Faker::App.name
    company_name = Faker::Company.name
    sequence(:name) { |n| "#{([app_name, company_name].sample)}#{n}" }
    defaults_hash = { 'item_type' => 'charity', 'child_item_type' => 'product'}
    defaults defaults_hash
  end
end
```

Comment: Show the organization Factory

Comment: What will return the expression `Organization.new.sources`  in the rails concole ?  And this  `Organization.last.sources`

Comment: So with a fresh app using mongoid 5 and factory girl 4.5, this is working fine.  Are you sure your organization is saving and failing on some model level validation?

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, but had trouble updating mongoid. Got this error from bundle:
`mongoid-rspec (>= 0) ruby depends on
      mongoid (~> 4.0.0) ruby`

Comment: @chumakoff `Organization.new.sources => nil` & `Organization.last.sources => #<Mongoid::Criteria selector: {"_id"=>{"$in"=>[BSON::ObjectId('54eb8b48746d6fbaae670000')]}} options: {} class: Source embedded: false> `